# parsley.js equalto Not invalidating if equal to field changes

Tags: c#, validation, webforms, parsley.js

I'm working in c# using web forms,
when integrating parsley for input validation it doesn't make the input with the 'equalto' arttirbute invalid if the equal to field changes.

```
<input type="password" runat="server" id="passwordTB" name="passwordTB" class="form-control" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-trigger="change" autocomplete="off" data-parsley-length="[7,40]" />
Repeat Password:
<input type="password" runat="server" id="passwordTBRepeat" name="passwordTBRepeat" class="form-control" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-trigger="change" data-parsley-equalto="#passwordTB" autocomplete="off" data-parsley-length="[7,40]" />
```

I would expect the passwordTBRepeat to validate itself and become invalid if passwordTB changed but it doesn't.

I'm using parsley v2.1.2 and jquery 2.1.4.

Is this by design or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, `Parsley` doesn't [deal very well with interdependencies](https://github.com/guillaumepotier/Parsley.js/issues/839).

For now, you could manually call `validate` when the source input updates.

Comment: It's next on my agenda, right after I finish stuff on promises

Comment: I came to the same conclusion with this issue.
I made a small function that calls validate on key up for the fields with the same data-parsley-group. 
Worked a charm!